# How to check if an array is contained in a collection?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Let's say I have

```
class A
{
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var text = ""
}

class B
{
    dynamic var id = 0
    let collection = List<A>
}
```

I would like to know if an array of `Int` (ids) is contained on `B.collection` (matching `id` property). Something like this

```
realm.objects(B).filter("%@ in collection.map{$0.id}", [1,2]) // pseudocode, obviously wrong
```

I would be happy enough being able to check if a single `Int` is contained by `collection` (again, testing `id` property). I tried using [`SUBQUERY`](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/) but I'm not able to find correct syntax.

Thanks

Comment: What is the List class? Why you don't use Array or Set? Then you can perform filter function.

Comment: @AlešOskarKocur:this is a dabase query, I'm first trying to see if the db engine provides any help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`realm.objects(B).filter("ANY collection.id IN %@", [1, 2])` will give you all `B` objects where `collection` has an `A` object with an `id` of 1 or 2.

Comment: Not exactly what I want since eI need 1 AND 2 to match, in any case it helps. Thanks!

Comment: `ANY collection.id = 1 AND ANY collection.id = 2` will do that, but there's no shorthand version that takes an array.